# Hide or show a variation attribute dropdown based another dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, drop-down-menu

I want to hide or show variation attribute dropdown based select another variation attribute dropdown of woocommerce single product pages. for example the variables of the products are as follows:

```
type-order  > name: "Jacket"   ,           value: "jacket"
              name: "Jacket and Pants"   , value: "jacket-pants"


jacket-type > name: "Jacket A" , value: "jacket1"
              name: "Jacket B" , value: "jacket2"
              name: "Jacket C" , value: "jacket3"

jacket-color > name: "green" , value: "Green"
               name: "black" , value: "Black"

jacket-pants-type > name: "Jacket with Pants A" , value: "jacket-pants-1"
                    name: "Jacket with Pants B" , value: "jacket-pants-2"
                    name: "Jacket with Pants C" , value: "jacket-pants-3"

jacket-pants-color > name: "green" , value: "Green"
                     name: "black" , value: "Black"
```

There are 5 variables in each product. I want to display only the dropdown `jacket-type` and `jacket-color` whenever the user selects option `type-order = jacket`. But when chooses `type-order = jacket-pants` , all the parameters can be displayed.

I tried the following code snippet but it didn't work

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'filter_dropdown_variation_args', 10, 1 );
function filter_dropdown_variation_args( $args ) {
    // Dont show "Choose an option"
    $args['show_option_none'] = false;

    // Remove the option value "2,5 kg"
    foreach( $args['options'] as $key => $option ){
        if( $option === "2,5 kg" ) {
            unset($args['options'][$key]);
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
```